# Getting a date format error while executing

Tags: sql, oracle, date

ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
01840. 00000 -  "input value not long enough for date format"
*Cause:
*Action:

```
SELECT TO_DATE (
          TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (attribute39, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
          'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "PO Valid To Date"
  FROM table;
```

Want to execute the query without error,
attribute39 is date formate in mm/dd/yyyy and varchar(250)

Comment: How does a MySQL DB produce a Oracle error message? Do you want us to guess which query failed or will you add it to your question?

Comment: Which values do you have in ATTRIBUTE39? Code you posted suggests that ATTRIBUTE39 contains strings (so is VARCHAR2 datatype) as you're trying convert it to DATE, then back to string (using TO_CHAR), and then again to date (using TO_DATE). Why? Perhaps you should explain what you have (source data) and desired result because that code is *wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE supports 'DEFAULT return_value ON CONVERSION ERROR' and if you prefix the date format with 'FX' you will be able to detect rows where attribute39 is not exactly compliant to your expectation:

```
TO_DATE (attribute39, DEFAULT to_date('01/01/0001','dd/mm/yyyy') ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'FXMM/DD/YYYY')
```

You could put NULL as DEFAULT if you don't have it as possible value for attribute39, if not selecting a value you are sure is not in your data makes easier to detect rows with invalid attribute39.

You may get ORA-01840 if you have strings where the year is only two digits (meaning from 1950 to 2049).

You could also run a query with a regex to detect unexpected values in attribute39.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(col1)     
from Customer_flex_attr_value 
where regexp_like (col1, '([0-9][0-9]|3[0-1])/([0-9]|[0-9]{2})/[0-9]{4}') 
order by 1 desc;
```

This would bring different date format